# Is it possible to average a variable only when another variable is true?

Tags: r

```
mean(data$NumKilled if data$ForAffil = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This command doesn't work - is there a way to change it to command that R run the average of `data$NumKilled` when `data$ForAffil = TRUE` or when `data$ForAffil = Yes`?

Comment: there is almost certainly a way this can be done;  please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `mean(data$NumKilled[data$ForAffil == TRUE], na.rm = TRUE)`  or simpler `mean(data$NumKilled[data$ForAffil], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Or convert to data.table and compute. data <- as.data.table(data). Then val <- data[ForAffil == TRUE | ForAffil == “Yes”, mean(NumKilled)]